# Is There any way to Protect my App from Rooted phone

Tags: android, sqlite

I know this question asked multiple time, i have googled it too but not found any working answer.

I am developing a android App with sqlite database and want to secure my database.db file from rooted phone, I have applied the check for rooted Device using below code but its not working on some `Samsung` and `Redmi`.

```
public class CheckRooted {
    public static boolean isRooted() {

        // get from build info
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
            return true;
        }

        // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
        try {
            File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
            if (file.exists()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // ignore
        }

        // try executing commands
        return canExecuteCommand("su");
    }

    // executes a command on the system
    private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
        boolean executedSuccesfully;
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            executedSuccesfully = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            executedSuccesfully = false;
        }

        return executedSuccesfully;
    }
}
```

Also suggest me how to protect my database.db file from rooted phones, I can't use any paid services like GreenDao or others.

Comment: The data is on the client side, so assume it can't be trusted. As someone who has a rooted phone, and who has messed around with app's databases, I can tell you that it's very easy to do.

Comment: Actually i am developing a app which store some confidential data in local sqlite db, and before production of this we have to clear the security testing and security team are able to extract .db file from my app. and as far as i understand the android it is not possible without root, so that's why i ask for rooted device check which work for all devices.

Comment: Are you protecting the data from the device owner? Is the data provided with the app or is it added after the user get's the app?

Comment: @zaph : Data is added after the user get's the app.

Comment: Perhaps you missed that there were two (2) questions and one (1) response.

Comment: I want to ask from all of you, Is there any possibility to apply check of rooted device, who's work for all vendor's Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Android, but this can help you with your database encryption problem.

It is called "[SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/)".

Check it out. It also has a community edition, which is also allowed to be used with commercial apps.

---

Further more, if the root checks aren't working on some Samsung and Redmi Devices, make sure they do not use slightly different commands.

Try testing for multiple root commands instead of just one single one.

Comment: Hiow would the SQLCipher encryption key be secured?

Comment: @KampfFussel : As far as i understand this SQLCipher we have to make a password in device end, but security team will not allow any hard-coded password for data encryption.

Comment: You don't have to have a static encryption key. You could use the device id and a salt or a hash from the google account etc. You can calculate the encryption key on-the-fly.

Comment: seems good, i can go with these techniques, but problem is same, if security team break this logic then i have to change this.

Comment: Security is an ongoing thing. You will always have to adapt to new methods. I am just trying to show you some ways. Play around with them. Test them. See what fits your needs.